# Insert values into variables from SQL drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I'm trying to take in data from a MySQL database and put it into a drop down list, then take that data and put it into a variable.
But the variable ends up having a null value

```
<!--create a drop down list that contains all the classes-->
<form name="booking" method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <select name="class">
        <?php
        // fetches all classes from db
        $sql = "SELECT class_name FROM class";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            //Take in all the classes from the database
            echo '<option value=' . $row["class_ID"] . '>' . $row["class_name"] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <!--close the drop down list-->
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Select Class</button>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {
        //Input the value from the while loop into the $class variable
        $class_name = $row['class_ID'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM class where class_name =$class_name";
    }
    ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment all the $class_name variable is NULL but I want it to take the value class_ID from the database.

Comment: After you submit the form, the value (of the select) that was selected should be inside `$_POST['class']` and I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In 5. row you use select query and only take 1 field from db  'class_name'

In 9. row you wanna call 2 field from db 1:'class_ID' and 2:'class_name'

In 20. row you define the $class_name = $row['class_ID']; but it will return null because you call 1 field in 5. row

please look at code below.

```
<form name="booking" method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <select name="class">
        <?php
        // fetches all classes from db
        $sql = "SELECT class_name,class_ID FROM class";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            //Take in all the classes from the database
            echo '<option value=' . $row["class_ID"] . '>' . $row["class_name"] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <!--close the drop down list-->
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary">Select Class</button>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit_button"])) {
        //Input the value from the while loop into the $class variable
        $class_name = $_POST['class'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM class where class_name =$class_name";
    }
    ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```